# SQL script to modify DAY of Date field

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking help for SQL script (Oracle). My need is to change DAY field of DATE with a condition. Decrements 1 day when DATE is last day of month, else increment by 1 day. The date format is DD-MMM-YY HH:MM:SS AM/PM.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: really -- your date is stored as a string?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going assume your date field is actually a date or timestamp because if not you are in deep dog doo.

Here is how you do it:

```
update some_table_you_did_not_name
set date_field = case when EXTRACT( month from next_day(date_field)) <> EXTRACT(month from date_field) 
                      then date_field - 1 day
                      else date_field + 1 day
                 end
```

Comment: Beat me to it +1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - which part won't work -- the month function?

Comment: That and the invalid interval literal

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefmonthfunc.html

Comment: That's **not** the Oracle database manual. That's the manual for "JavaDB" (aka "Derby")

Answer (score 1):

```
update the_table
  set date_column = case 
                     when trunc(last_day(date_column)) = trunc(date_column) 
                       then date_column - 1
                      else date_column + 1
                    end;
```

The `trunc()` is necessary because Oracle `DATE` columns include a time part.